# Draggable button in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uibutton

I am trying to make a draggable button inside my uiwebview, so when the website is displayed you can move the button around the screen. I can make the button move when it is just placed in the viewcontroller. Do I need to do anything different when wanting it on my uiwebview?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If it works in a regular `UIViewController` then it should work. What I would suggest doing is using a `UIViewController` and add the `UIWebView` and your button as subviews. Make sure you have the button in front of the `UIWebView` though.